# Как осуществить транслитерацию тегов в Hugo?

Tags: golang, static

Наткнулся на такую проблему при генерации сайта с помощью [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/):
При создании тега для поста на русском языке, к примеру:

```
tags: ["спорт", "Активный отдых"]
```

Генератор автоматом создаёт папку "спорт" и "активный-отдых", так же ссылки на теги:

```
mysite.local/tags/спорт
mysite.local/tags/активный-отдых
```

Т.е. некоторые преобразования над именем тега Hugo делает ( Активный отдых != активный-отдых ), но не могу найти где возможно включить транслитерацию подобных ссылок т.е. *активный-отдых => aktivnyj-otdykh*.

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, заранее благодарю.